# Usage of ssehexec task in Jenkins build doesn't stop its execution

Tags: java, shell, ant, jenkins

I have an Ant Task in the Jenkins Ant Execution Plugin, as a Post Build Step, to remotely run a shell script in one of our servers. The shell scripts starts a java process in the background. When I execute the shell script on the server directly it starts the java process in the back ground and comes out. When I run it from Jenkins via the `sshexec` task the shell script is run, but it never comes out and the Jenkins Build waits.

Later when I added the `timeout` attribute onto the `sshexec` it times out after the given number of milliseconds, but the Jenkins build is shown as failed. How do I make the sshexec task to come out cleanly from the shell script execution?

Here is my `ssheexec` task

```
<sshexec host="${deploy.host}" username="${deploy.username}"  password="${deploy.password}" command=". /etc/profile; cd ${deploy.path}; sh start.sh i1" trust="true" timeout="10000" />
```

The **start.sh** file is as given:

```
nohup java -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -cp calculation.jar com.tes.StartCalculation $1 &

echo $! > calculation-$1-java.pid
```

Comment: Does the task work outside jenkins? Say directly invoked from command prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like, the ssh executed job is not fully **daemonized**.  Starting with `nohup` is not sufficient in many cases.

See the [discussion](https://github.com/jenkinsci/publish-over-ssh-plugin/pull/1) that related to it (in a different context)

> The issue is that you are not closing your file descriptors when you
>   push something into the background. The & is fine when you are in a
>   shell, but is not enough when you want to disconnect and leave a
>   process running, you need the process to disconnect from the shell.

....  Fix to to correct the script.

> If someone writes a naive service script that does not properly detach
>   from the terminal, I want to know the first time that that script is
>   used in a deployment - the SCM changes will enable the breaking change
>   to be quickly identified.
>
> It is wrong to hide the problem to enable incorrect code to be
>   released to production - and I would not be happy if the first I knew
>   about it was when a production system administrator complained.

If this is the same problem, you need to [daemonize the script](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/61539-daemonizing-bash-script.html)